# using iSync plugins in OS X 10.7 and later

Tags: macos, applications

iSync is being phased out from OS X. In 10.7 Lion, it doesn't come with it pre-installed any more.

I have purchased an iSync plugin for my mobile phone. I am currently using iSync in Lion using a version downloaded from the Internet (in a previous version of this question that didn't work, but this has since been resolved, it was an installation glitch). So at the moment, everything is fine, but I'm not sure for how long this will work.

Will I still be able to sync contacts and calendars with my mobile phone (a Samsung B2100) once iSync won't work on OS X at all any more (presumably when Mountain Lion comes out in may)? Is there a product that will continue to work that can deal with iSync plugins?

Comment: What *exactly* are you using iSync for that other utilities won't do?

Comment: @Timothy synchronizing contacts and calendar entries through Bluetooth with a Samsung mobile phone (B2100).

Comment: If you let me know where to get the packages from, I can test iSync in ML for you.

Comment: Hi @Pekka - your bounty is close to running out with no answers - as I mention above, if you let me know where you got your fiels from I can perform a test in ML Dev Preview and see if it still works.

Comment: Hi @Stuffe, thanks, that would be great! Here's the download link: http://jools.me/iSync.zip I don't know the person providing the download so install at your own risk. It [looks trustworthy](http://www.mail-archive.com/wamug@wamug.org.au/msg66593.html) though.

Answer (score 1):

Works a treat*

[image]

- No guarantee that it will continue to work a treat!

Comment: Thanks stuffe! It is very nice to know that at least for the next iteration, the underlying framework still is in place.